# Query string is empty always in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, query-string

I want hide some content on the wp page depends on query string for example

```
site/article/name/?nosidebar=1
```

I use $_GET['nosidebar'] to check the property value. It works on local server but $_GET array is empty all the time on remote server. I tried add custom property to public properties via following code

```
$GLOBALS['wp']->add_query_var( 'nobsidebar' );
```

but still get_query_var('nosidebar') and $_GET['nosidebar'] still returns nothing. Does anyone have an idea why it happens and how can I solve it?